# I want to add icon on the right of MultiAutoComleteTextView in Android

Tags: android

I need to add delete icon at the right side of the selected item from MultiAutoCompleteTextView in Android

Comment: create custom MultiAutoComleteTextView)

Comment: if you have got your answer than accept answer so other can get help from your contribution

Answer (score 2):

see this property of `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/yourIcon"

  <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/yourIcon"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="MultiAutoCompleteTextView" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute in your AutoCompleteTextView.

> android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete_icon"

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the icon in xml Layout of MultiAutoCompleteTextView